# Jquery keypress event ignore arrow keys

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an input box that acts like a search (similar to facebook).
I am using the jquery on key-press event which works fine.
The problem is that I can't scroll down on the set of the results using the arrow keys, every time that one of them is pressed the search results are being regenerated.
So is it possible to ignore the arrow keys / shift / tab etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/UU6KG/

```
$("#search-form .search-terms").on("keypress", function(){
       $("#search-items #autocom").fadeIn();
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to filter out the arrow key codes (37,38,39,40), try this:

*Note the `function(e)` in place of `function()` - this allows you to grab the event and therefore the key code.*

```
$('#search-form .search-terms').on('keydown', function(e){
    // get keycode of current keypress event
    var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);

    // do nothing if it's an arrow key
    if(code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40) {
        return;
    }

    // do normal behaviour for any other key
    $('#search-items #autocom').fadeIn();
});
```

**[Click for a list of key codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)**

A note from the docs on `keypress`/`keyup`/`keydown`:

> Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice.

The `keypress` event works in **almost** all situations but it's prudent to use `keyup` or `keydown` because some browsers (I think some older version of Firefox) don't detect certain keys, such as *arrow keys*, using the `keypress` event.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer, updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UU6KG/1/

Answer (score 2):

I would also submit that you should be ignoring other keys that should not directly result in a new query. Keys like `shift`, `scroll-lock`, and `end`, for example. After consulting the same [keycode list](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) that @theyetiman linked to, I came up with this if statement to ignore all keys that shouldn't matter (note the swap of `keypress` for `keyup` to allow capture of important keys like `backspace`):

```
$('.search-terms').on('keyup', function(ev) {
    if ((ev.keyCode > = 9 && ev.keyCode <= 45) || (ev.keyCode >= 91 || ev.keyCode <= 93) || (ev.keyCode >= 112 || ev.keyCode <= 145)) {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: List of codes is interesting, but there's probably a mistake in the logic of the condition (I'm guilty of copy+pasting!).
Also, in your example, the space char is ignored. For the other copy+pasters: It's fine if they're typing at the end, but if the user has arrowed left and pressed space, the data may change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".search-terms").live('keydown',function(event){                  
if(event.which>=37 && event.which<=40)
                {
                    reutrn;

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !Main.IsEmptyOrNull( event ) )
{
    $( document ).keydown( function ( e )
    {
        switch ( e.which )
        {
            case 16:
            case 17:
            case 18:
            case 37:
            case 38:
            case 39:
            case 40:
                break;
            default:
                var that = event.target;
                that.rows = that.getAttribute( 'data-min-rows' ) | 0, that.rows;
                that.rows = that.scrollHeight / 16 ;
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add an explanation to your code, and why your solution is equivalent or better than the other answers. Without any explanation like the other answers have, your post risks being downvoted or removed.

Answer (score 0):

The code from `theyetiman` can be shortened a bit like so:

```
$('#search-form .search-terms').on('keydown', function(e){
    // do nothing if it's an arrow key
    if ([37,38,39,40].indexOf(e.keyCode || e.which) !== -1) {
        return;
    }

    // do normal behaviour for any other key
    $('#search-items #autocom').fadeIn();
});
```